# What does digest algorithm means in open_ssl encryption PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, hash, public-key-encryption

When we config our encryption algorithm in php with `open_ssl`, we can create our own configuration, now, I don't know what does `digest_alg` means and how `sha1` (hash) is related to my encryption.

**What does it do exactly ?**

```
$config = array(
    'digest_alg' => 'sha1',
    'private_key_bits' => 2048,
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);
```

---

I already tried to Google it and I didn't find anything, and I don't want a good book to start with.

Comment: THen here is not the place to ask. You need th look at a proper book on the subject

Comment: @RiggsFolly I didn't understand you, can you explain?

Comment: You are using outdated array syntax and outdated, deprecated sha1 algorithm.

Comment: @DanielW. Thanks, I will not use sha1 , don't worry